# Sort a Json by user.id from a JSON

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON in which I save the GuildID and then again the UserID

```
   "385524088980111362": {
         "672748733737467936": {
             "XP": 0,
             "Level": 1,
             "BisLevel": 100,
             "NächsteXP": 0,
             "XPIns": 2
         },
        "866935358448468008": {
            "XP": 0,
            "Level": 1,
            "BisLevel": 100,
             "NächsteXP": 0,
             "XPIns": 7
         }
     }
```

Now I want to sort the users by XPIns from one Guild. I remember this code part here

```
let obj;
fs.readFile('./xpdata.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err; 
    obj = JSON.parse(data)

    var sorted = Object.entries(obj).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])
});
```

In the end, the user with more should be in the 1st position (866935358448468008). Can anyone help me?

I've seen a similar question before but couldn't get it to work if there was a GuildID in front of it

The code I had done before (sorry for the sloppy code that was a year ago (Code is updated)):

```
let obj;
                    fs.readFile('./userdata.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
                        if (err) throw err;
        
                        try {
                            obj = JSON.parse(data)
                        } catch (error) {
                            if(error) return console.log("Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten! " + error);
                        }
        
                        var sorted = Object.entries(obj).sort((a, b) => b[1].Economy.Balance - a[1].Economy.Balance)
                        if(sorted.length > 10) sorted = sorted.slice(0, 10)
        
                        var lBString = "";
        
                        var s = 1;
                        sorted.forEach(user => {
                            let usertag = Data[user[0]].Tag
                            lBString += `${s}. ${usertag} • **${user[1].Economy.Balance}$**\n`
                            s = s += 1
                        })

                        let embed = {
                            title: `Leaderboard Balance`,
                            description: lBString,
                            color: 0xFFFF00,
                            thumbnail: {
                                url: client.user.avatarURL(),
                            },
                            timestamp: new Date(),
                            footer: {
                                text: footer,
                                icon_url: client.user.avatarURL(),
                            },
                            
                        }
    
                        e.reply({embeds: [embed]});
                    });
```

Comment: You cannot sort objects in JavaScript, did you mean to have the outer structure an array instead?

Comment: I have used something like this before but without the GuildID. There I looked to see what was bigger and then output the highest 10 users. Here I only want to get the user with the highest XPIns. (I add something else to my description)

Comment: My code from earlier is attached. But now I want to get only the top user. Sorted by XPIns from 1 Guild

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want the highest ranking user in terms of `"XPIns"`, I suggest you use a [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) call on the entries of the inner object.

```js
const data = {
    "385524088980111362": {
        "672748733737467936": {
            "XP": 0,
            "Level": 1,
            "BisLevel": 100,
            "NächsteXP": 0,
            "XPIns": 2
        },
        "866935358448468008": {
            "XP": 0,
            "Level": 1,
            "BisLevel": 100,
            "NächsteXP": 0,
            "XPIns": 7
        }
    }
};

const topUser = Object.entries(data['385524088980111362']).reduce((acc, cur) => (
    acc[1]?.XPIns > cur[1]?.XPIns ? acc : cur
), []);
console.log(topUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do in cases like this is to use another object as index using a reference of the main array/object

ie:

```
var index = {};
// replace .id with the attribute you want to use. In your case XPins
index[ object.id ] = main_index_reference;
```

once you have generated the index, then you can get the keys using `Object.keys( index )`:

```
var keys = Object.keys( index );
keys.forEach( function( key ){
   var element = main_object[ key ];
   // do whatever with the element
} );
```

Your main_object remains unchanged. In your particular case you want the highest value, all you need to do is to extract the last element from the keys array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this. However, the users do not have their ID inside their object, so you'd probably have to patch the ID before sorting.

```js
const data = {
  // if the guild could have list of users then it would have been much better
  // instead of Object list with ID, Array of objects with ID in it works much faster..
  "385524088980111362": {
    "672748733737467936": {
      // if we had user ID here, then it would have been better
      "XP": 0,
      "Level": 1,
      "BisLevel": 100,
      "NächsteXP": 0,
      "XPIns": 2
    },
    "866935358448468008": {
      "XP": 0,
      "Level": 1,
      "BisLevel": 100,
      "NächsteXP": 0,
      "XPIns": 7
    }
  }
};


function getSortedUsersByXPins(data, guildId) {
  // if guild has array of users, then we won't need Object.values
  const sorted = Object.values(data[guildId]).sort((user1, user2) => {
    return user2.XPins - user1.XPins
  });

  return sorted;
}

const sorted = getSortedUsersByXPins(data, '385524088980111362');

console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with this solution, in case you want to convert the object to a list. The main issue is the missing `identifier` if you work with a list.

This assumes that you would use a function like `Object.entries` before to convert it.

My recommendation: Include the `id` into the object and convert it to a list.

```js
 
 
 
 
 let guildList = [
      {
        "XP": 0,
        "Level": 1,
        "BisLevel": 100,
        "NächsteXP": 0,
        "XPIns": 2,
        "Id": "672748733737467936"
      },
      {
        "XP": 0,
        "Level": 1,
        "BisLevel": 100,
        "NächsteXP": 0,
        "XPIns": 7,
        "Id": "866935358448468008"
      }
    ];
    

let aSorted = guildList.sort((a, b) => b.XPIns-a.XPIns)
console.log(aSorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just extract the player objects and sort them, pretty much the way you already described (`(p1, p2) => p2.XPIns - p1.XPIns`).

Here is an example:

```js
const data = {
  "385524088980111362": {
    "672748733737467936": {
      "XP": 0,
      "Level": 1,
      "BisLevel": 100,
      "NächsteXP": 0,
      "XPIns": 2
    },
    "866935358448468008": {
      "XP": 0,
      "Level": 1,
      "BisLevel": 100,
      "NächsteXP": 0,
      "XPIns": 7
    }
  }
}

const res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).map( ([gid, users]) => [gid, Object.entries(users).map(([id, u]) => ({id, ...u })).sort( (u1, u2) => u2.XPIns - u1.XPIns)] ))
console.log(res)
```

Note that you cannot create an object with player id as key without losing the order, since JS objects always put numeric keys in ascending order.